# PhpExcel Load a dynamic template

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am trying to load an excel xlsx file template which is dynamic, I tried with the following method :

```
$approve_employee_id = $this->input->post('approve_employee_id');
$query = "SELECT * from employee where employee.employee_id='$approve_employee_id'";
        $query = $this->db->query($query);
        foreach ($query->result() as $value) {
            $f_name = $value->f_name;
            $s_name = $value->s_name;
            $user_name = $value->user_name;
            $under_score = "_";
            $file_name = $user_name . $under_score . $approve_month_id . $under_score . $approve_year_name;
            $folder_name = $approve_month_id . $approve_year_name;

            $basedir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/timesheet/files";
            $this->load->library('excel');


            $objPHPexcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/timesheet/files/un_approved/'$file_name'.xlsx");
            echo 'Loading template successfull...';
            $objWorksheet = $objPHPexcel->getActiveSheet();
}
```

How can I load the  file name in a dynamic way? 
The following is one of the  file's name : HS103_January_2014

Comment: So what problem are you actually having? Does it load the template file? Does it display any error messages? Do you really have single quotes in your filenames?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the filename you're trying to load:

```
"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/timesheet/files/un_approved/'$file_name'.xlsx"
```

If the value of `$file_name` is `HS103_January_2014`, then this will try to load

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/timesheet/files/un_approved/'HS103_January_2014'.xlsx
```

Does it really have single quotes in the actual filename?

Use

```
$objPHPexcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(
    "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/timesheet/files/un_approved/{$file_name}.xlsx"
);
```